# Linked List Java adding elements

Tags: java, linked-list

I am learning linked lists in java and I  have problem with the first element that is being enrolled twice. How to fix this problem. Here is my code :

```
if (head==null) {
        head=new Node(data);

        }
        Node current=head; 

        while(current.getNext()!=null) {
            current=current.getNext();

        }
        current.setNext(new Node(data));// how to change this line 

}
```

https://pastebin.com/2PCvJmKT

Comment: you call `new Node(data)` twice

Comment: I think the second part needs to be in an `else` branch: _either_ head is null (and you want to create a new head), _or_ it's not null (and you want to append to what's already there). If you indent your code properly (your IDE or editor should be able to do this for you), you might have spotted this yourself.

Comment: To not have element added twice, don't create two `Node` objects with the same `data`. This isn't at all a question for SO, I feel. Edit: Think about what your code must actually do (without looking at the code *at all*). Write that down. Then look at the code. Does it do what you've just written? If not, fix the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add return, after adding first element.

```
if (head==null) {
     head = new Node(data);
     return;
}
```

I took code from link.

Answer (score 0):

In pastebin, this code snippet is a part of your "insert"-function.
So in the code snippet you're looking upon the case "What if my LinkedList is empty? -> no elements in list -> no head

If that's the case, you just want to add the new data into the empty List as an new Node(data).

But what you're doing right now is: You're creating a new Node for an empty list, set that Node as Head and iterating through a list with just one element. That practically means, that you will never enter your while loop. After that you're adding a Node with the same data as the Head as its successor.